# How to fix Wildfly 8 GC overhead limit error

Tags: jakarta-ee, wildfly

I have a java web app running on a server using wildfly 8.2 as the application server. Currently the server is able to run for a few hours (+- 8) when it will suddenly crash, before the crash Java platform SE Binary will be using approximately 1 to 8% of the CPU but as the webapp crashes it jumps to 40+%

The problem does not sit in the code as when the webapp is run from another server it can run for days at a time. It only happens on the production environment where there are multiple users at a time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Created the question/answer as wildfly documentation is woefully inadequate in answering these types of problems.

The issue sits in a bug in wildfly 8 that caused it to run a default heap size that was too small for larger web based applications even if you tried to increase it.

upgrading to the newest wildfly (15.0.0.Final at time of writing) seems to fix the bug as heap sizes reflect correctly now